# ReSharper treats Resource strings as nullable in string.Format

Tags: c#, resharper

I am using ReSharper with Value analysis set to pessimistic and would like to get rid of a false positive.

When I have some code like this:

```
throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(Resources.ExceptionParamFormat, myParam));
```

ReSharper tells me about a "Possible 'null' assignment to entity marked with 'NotNull' attribute" for the call to `string.Format`, because it is not sure that `Resources.ExceptionParamFormat` always returns a `[NotNull]` string.

I am searching for a good way to stop ReSharper from warning me about this particular type of a possible null assignment, when the Resource exists.

I could add `// ReSharper disable once AssignNullToNotNullAttribute`
 to all calls to `string.Format` that use a resource string, but this can easily ignore too much or the wrong thing, when there are more `[NotNull]` parameters on the same line.

Comment: Hi, the resource might exist, but, do you have a Default Value for that Resource? That might be the problem.

Comment: @Nekeniehl The resource does have a default value. This happens in a new project when I add the Jetbrains.Annotations Nuget package, set Resharper to pessimistic, add a formatstring to the default Resource file and try to use it in a call to `string.Format`.